# How to Automate Chromium Browser in Code UI Test

Tags: automation, automated-tests, desktop-application, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

Currently i am automating the Desktop Application using CodedUI tests.

I am facing some challenges, there are inside Desktop application we having Chromium browser concept. Unable to record the chromium browser element and getting the element. If normal web page in the Desktop application, i can able to record and get all the wen elements.

So can you anyone help me how to get all the element in the chromium browser using Coded Ui test

Comment: Hi @Sarvannakumar, I'm also facing the same issue like you. Did you find the solution how to automate chromium embedded framework data using coded ui?

Answer (score 0):

> I overlooked the question date. But still I posted it as answer, Because I think, still it would be helpful for others to get rid of the problem mentioned in question.

I too had the same issue. After lot of R&D, I found it's very hard (perhaps impossible) to automate CEF using Coded UI.

However, it can be automated using selenium. Moreover, selenium is easy to integrate within coded UI test, if you wish to not leave coded UI.

Here's some links which you can refer how to automate CEF using selenium:

[Chromium Embeded Frameowrk using chromedriver.](https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/UsingChromeDriver.md)

[GitHub Example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/49/CefSharp.Example/CefExample.cs#L44)

[Example Framework](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)